# Clear padding in column product info Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have site and using Bootstrap 3. I have problem with my product grid. I need to remove padding from my product list.
[www.shop11.kg](http://shop11.kg)
Sorry my English.
Thanks

[image: Image Link Here]

```
<div class="tab-content">
<!-- Start gridview products -->
<div id="grid-view" class="tab-pane fade in active" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Start Single profuct -->
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="single-product">
                <div class="product-thumb">
                    <a href="/product/1264">
                        <img class="front-img" src="/public/images/noimage/noimage_262.jpeg" alt="img">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <div class="pro-title">
                        <h4>
                            <a href="/product/1264" title="ARIEL COLOR Стиральный порошок для цветного белья автомат 15 кг ">
                                ARIEL COLOR Стиральный порошок для цветного белья автомат 15 кг
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pro-price-ratting">
                        <div class="price-box">
                            <span class="price">1580 сом</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-action">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pro-btn add-to-cart">Купить</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Single profuct -->
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End gridview products -->
```

Comment: Do you make one row for all products or one row for each product ? From your example it would be the last one. From your image I wouldn´t say its a padding problem. More a float one, look at https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/clearfix/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` and `flex-flow:row wrap` in your row class so all the items will be wrapped properly i.e

```
.row{
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
 }
```

Comment: Where I have to past?

Comment: In your css file or you can use inline css `<div class="row" style="display:flex; flex-flow:row wrap;">`

Answer (score 0):

You can give css like

```
.cp-right-products .tab-pane .col-md-3:nth-child(4n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

in tablet view you can give css like

```
.cp-right-products .tab-pane .col-md-3:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
```

then all items will be arrange properly.